# program adds on a string seemingly out of nowhere

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

I'm writing a code that reads in an input file from stdin, and outputs the exact same content (to stdout) except that replaces any words found in the "dictionary" in the following way, in the exact order:

1. if the word exactly as it is stored as a key in dictionary appears, then find the corresponding value pair and print that out instead.
2. if the word that's capitalized properly (eg., Thomas, with capital first letter and lowercase for everything else) is a valid key in the dictionary, print out the corresponding value pair instead
3. if the lowercased version is a valid key, print out its corresponding value
4. if there are no matches, just print things out as they are.
   (All non-alphabetical characters are just printed out "normally".)

A problem I've been having though is that when I'm doing (2), somehow a character ('U') gets tagged on to the end of the "string" or copy2 array when I'm testing "IPSUM" (all cap).

For instance, see this output:
[image]
My outputs are in the lines with "<", and the ">" indicate what should've been. Based on the order I'm checking things, since IPSUM is not in the dictionary (see the end of this post for contents of dictionary), it goes to (2) where IPSUM should become Ipsum, and it should print out the corresponding value of Ipsum. But instead I get IpsumU, and so the dictionary doesn't recognize the word. But I'm not sure where the 'U' is coming from, since the input is exactly

> IPSUM (all cap).

Could anyone help me figure out what might be wrong with my code?

```
//for reference:
typedef struct HashBucketEntry {
  void *key;
  void *data;
  struct HashBucketEntry *next;
} HashBucketEntry;

typedef struct HashTable {
  int size;
  unsigned int (*hashFunction)(void *);
  int (*equalFunction)(void*, void*);
  HashBucketEntry  **buckets;
} HashTable;

//We have a Hashtable *dictionary.

void processInput() {
 //char c;
 int c; 
 int i = 0;
 //char * word = (char *) malloc(60 * sizeof(char));
 char word[60]; 
 while (c = getchar()) {
     if (isalpha(c)) {
         word[i] = c;
         i++;
     } else {
         word[i] = '\0';
         if (word[0] != '\0') {
             //char * copy = (char *) malloc(60 * sizeof(char));
             char copy[60];
             strcpy(copy, word);
            
             unsigned int location = (dictionary->hashFunction)(copy) % (dictionary->size);
             char * word_in_dict;
             if (dictionary->buckets[location] != NULL) {
                word_in_dict = (char *) dictionary->buckets[location]->data;
             } else {
                word_in_dict = NULL;
             }
             char copy2[60];
             copy2[0] = toupper(copy[0]);
             for(int i = 1; copy[i]; i++){
                 copy2[i] = tolower(copy[i]);
             }
             unsigned int location2 = (dictionary->hashFunction)(copy2) % (dictionary->size);
             char * word_in_dict2;
             if (dictionary->buckets[location2] != NULL) { //somehow this is NULL when IPSUM, even though copy2 has correct string
                word_in_dict2 = (char *) dictionary->buckets[location2]->data; 
             } else {
                word_in_dict2 = NULL;
             }
 
             char copy3[60];
             for(int i = 0; copy[i]; i++){
                 copy3[i] = tolower(copy[i]);
             }
             unsigned int location3 = (dictionary->hashFunction)(copy3) % (dictionary->size);
             char * word_in_dict3;
             if (dictionary->buckets[location3] != NULL) {
                word_in_dict3 = (char *) dictionary->buckets[location3]->data;
             } else {
                word_in_dict3 = NULL;
             }

             if (word_in_dict != NULL) {
                 fprintf(stdout, "%s", word_in_dict);
             } else if (word_in_dict2 != NULL) {
                 fprintf(stdout, "%s", word_in_dict2);
             } else if (word_in_dict3 != NULL) {
                 fprintf(stdout, "%s", word_in_dict3);
             } else {
                 //fprintf(stdout, "%s", copy);
                 printf("%s", copy);

             }
             putchar(c);
             i = 0;
         } else if (c != EOF) {
             putchar(c);
         } else {
             break;
         }
     }
 }
}
```

The dictionary contains only these entries:

```
ipsum i%#@!
fubar fubar
IpSum XXXXX24
Ipsum YYYYY211
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Update in response to the answer:
I changed the code for copy2 to this:

```
for(j = 1; j < strlen(copy); j++) {
     if (j < sizeof(copy2)) {
          copy2[j] = tolower(copy[j]);
     }
}
```

(and did a similar thing to copy3). The second case works, but now the third case fails; things only seem to work if I change the second case but not the third case. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: First, `char c` must be `int c` because `fgetc()` returns `int`. It is a beginner's mistake to think "a character must be `char`" (or that "a number must be an integer"). Second, the loop ending condition is incorrect. It should be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: ... I see you've dealt with the `EOF` at the end of the loop body, making the code awkward and harder to follow.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show (copy&paste) the expected and actual as text and make clear which is what. Is `IPSUM (all cap).` the only input?

Comment: @WeatherVane I've fixed the code so that it's a little better, hopefully!

Comment: also, do I need to be freeing the arrays? I seem to be storing remnants of previous words stored—while "word" doesn't contain those remnants, somehow the copy, copy2, and copy3 all do

Comment: @norwegian_forest, no, you do not free automatic arrays, only those that you allocate dynamically.  That the parts of your arrays that you do not overwrite with something else continue to hold their previous contents is to be expected.  If you are treating them as *strings* then that is of no account.  On the other hand, if you are treating the whole arrays as significant then you need to manage their whole contents, regardless of whether they are dynamically or automatically (or statically) allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to creaty modified copies of your input strings, e.g.

```
             char copy2[60];
             copy2[0] = toupper(copy[0]);
             for(int i = 1; copy[i]; i++){
                 copy2[i] = tolower(copy[i]);
             }
```

does not copy the terminating `'\0'`. As automatic variables are not implicitly initialized, the corresponding memory may contain any data (from prevous loop cycles or from unrelated code) which may appear as trailing characters. You must append a `'\0'` character after the last character of your string.

This error may result in out-of-bounds access to the array when you access it as a string if there is no `'\0'` within the array bounds. (undefined behavior)

Your code itself might result in out-of-bounds access if the input string is too long. You should add a check to prevent access to array elements at `i >= sizeof(copy2)`.

I suggest something like this:

```
             char copy2[60];
             copy2[0] = toupper(copy[0]);
             /* avoid reading past the end of an empty string */
             if(copy[0]) {
                 for(int i = 1; copy[i] && (i < sizeof(copy)-1); i++){
                     copy2[i] = tolower(copy[i]);
                 }
                 /* variable i will already be incremented here */
                 copy2[i] = '\0';
             }
```

---

**Edit** as a response to a question in a comment:

You cannot combine `strcpy` and `tolower`, but you can copy the string first and modify the characters in-place afterwards.

Example:

```
    char copy2[60];
    if(strlen(copy) y sizeof(copy2)) {
        strcpy(copy2, copy);
        copy2[0] = toupper(copy2[0]);
        if(copy[0]) {
            /* The length has been checked before, no need to check again here */
            for(int i = 1; copy[i]; i++) {
                copy2[i] = tolower(copy2[i]);
            }
            /* the string is already terminated */
        }
    } else {
        /* string too long, handle error */
    }
```

or with truncating instead of reporting an error

```
    char copy2[60];
    strncpy(copy2, copy, sizeof(copy)-1);
    copy2[sizeof(copy2)-1] = '\0';
    copy2[0] = toupper(copy2[0]);
    if(copy[0]) {
        /* A long string would have been truncated before, no need to check the length here */
        for(int i = 1; copy[i]; i++) {
            copy2[i] = tolower(copy2[i]);
        }
        /* the string is already terminated */
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion—is this what you meant (please see the end of my original post where I've updated some code snippet? I still seem to have the same problem, however, where I still have that U tagged on.

Comment: No, @norwegian_forest, the code you added is not a correct implementation of what this answer describes.  The loop in that code terminates when `copy[j]` refers to the terminator of string `copy`.  It follows that the terminator for `copy2` should go into `copy2[j]`, but you instead put it in `copy2[j+1]`.

Comment: But also, @norwegian_forest, how about simplifying your code and avoiding making places for such errors to lodge by using the built-in `strcpy()` function, or perhaps `strcat()` or `strncat()`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh, I didn't know that was possible. based on a quick search, would something like this ``` strcpy(copy2[1], tolower(copy[1])) ``` after the first character suffice?

Comment: also, I had made some other changes to code before seeing your suggestion, and had a question—could you refer to the original post again?